# Probability that $010$ is present in an $n$-length binary sequence

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, information-theory, combinatorics-on-words, bit-strings

Imagine a memoryless source that outputs 0's and 1's with probabilities $P_X(0)$ and $P_X(1)$. For example, $P_{X^2}(00)=P_X(0)P_X(0)$.

How would you calculate the probability that the sequence $010$ is present in an $n$-length binary sequence?

What I have thought so far is that,

$$P[010 \text{ is in an } n\text{-length sequence}]=(n-3)P_X(0)^{\#0}P_X(1)^{\#1}$$

I am sure that I have to multiply the probabilities $P_X(0)$ and $P_X(1)$ by $n-3$, because I need to take into consideration all the possible combinations in which $010$ can appear (e.g. $\{010...x\}$,$\{x010...x\}$,etc.). But I am not sure about the number of zeros $\#0$ and the number of ones $\#1$.

Comment: This is not clear.   Are you considering the universe of binary sequences generated by, say, the repeated tosses of a (possibly unfair) coin?  Something else?

Comment: You seem to have a lot of double counting problems.  If the sequence starts $01010$ aren't you counting it twice?

Comment: @lulu I mean a memoryless source that outputs 0's and 1's with independent probabilities.

Comment: So, edit your post to say that clearly.

Comment: To your question:  You'll need to work recursively to avoid double counting.  I suggest starting from the fact that every sufficiently long "good" sequence must end in one of $1,00, 110$.

Comment: I could be overlooking elegant analysis.  To the best of my knowledge, there are only two approaches, neither of which is easy: [1] The indirect approach [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), where you take the $(2^n)$ possible sequences, deduct all the ways that the sequence can occur **at least once**, add back the ways that the sequence can occur **at least twice**, and so forth. ...see next comment

Comment: [2] The direct approach, where you let $E_k ~: k \in \{1,2,\cdots, (n-2)\}$ represent the $(n-2)$ **non-independent** events of the string "010" starting on the $k$-th digit.  You then (somehow) calculate the probability that none of the $E_k$ events occur.  ...see next comment

Comment: Actually, my last two comments have computed the probability that the "010" string does not occur, which is the complement of what you asked.  Anyway, one approach is to let $n$ range from $4$ through $10$ inclusive, use the computer to determine the number of sequences (out of $2^n$ sequences) that do have the "010" string.  Then, you look for a pattern in the data, try to form a hypothesis based on the pattern, and then try to analytically prove the hypothesis.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed the comment of @lulu, where she mentioned *recursion*.  This (3rd) way might very plausibly be best.

Comment: @lulu If I understand your comment correctly, I'm wondering how it would deal with "$\ldots 00100$"?

Comment: @BrianMoehring  My comment was pretty vague.  In the given problem, I'd divide the good sequences into $4$ types, according to whether they end in $11,01,00$ or $10$.  I haven't written it out, but I think that's good enough...after all, the only banned action is to add a $0$ to the type ending in $01$. For longer 'forbidden' blocks, you'd need to consider more endings.

Comment: @BrianMoehring  Should add, that the straight recursive method won't work terribly well if $n$ is huge.  Though, of course, that objection tends to hold for many counting methodologies.

Comment: Should note that the posted solution, from @Onir, follows a more or less similar methodolgy to the one I am sketching.

Comment: If $p$ is the probability of a $1$ and $q=1-p$ the probability of a $0$, then there will be a degree 3 or 4 recurrence, perhaps $$a(n)=2a(n-1)-(1+qp)a(n-2) +qp(1+p)a(n-3)-qp^2a(n-4)$$ starting with $a(0)=a(1)=a(2)=0$ and $a(3)=qp^2$.  This is theoretically solvable as a closed form, but as with cubic equations it is not worth the effort.

Comment: See OEIS [A000253](http://oeis.org/A000253)

Answer (score 4):

Let $a(00,n), a(01,n), a(10,n), a(11,n)$ be the probability we get a sequence that doesn't contain $010$ and end in each of the finishes.

We get:

$a(00,n+1)=p(a(00,n) + a(10,0))$

$a(01,n+1) = (1-p)(a(00,n)+a(10,n))$

$a(10,n+1) = pa(11,n)$

$a(11,n+1) = (1-p)(a(01,n) + a(11,n))$

We can write this as:

$\begin{pmatrix}
p & 0 & p & 0 \\
1-p & 0 & 1-p & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1-p & 0 & 1-p \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a(00,n) \\
a(01,n) \\
a(10,n)\\
a(11,n)
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a(00,n+1) \\
a(01,n+1) \\
a(10,n+1)\\
a(11,n+1)
\end{pmatrix} $

When $n=2$ the values are $(p^2,p(1-p),(1-p)p,(1-p)^2)$. Hence we have:

$\begin{pmatrix}
p & 0 & p & 0 \\
1-p & 0 & 1-p & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1-p & 0 & 1-p \\
\end{pmatrix}^{n-2}
\begin{pmatrix}
p^2 \\
p(1-p)\\
(1-p)p\\
(1-p)^2
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a(00,n) \\
a(01,n) \\
a(10,n)\\
a(11,n)
\end{pmatrix} $

If the matrix happens to be diagonalizable you can get explicit formulas, even if it isn't you can expect to put it in a good form. You can also use exponentiation by squaring for rapid computations.

Comment: Oh, there is $p$ and $1-p$ ? I need to change the transition matrix then.

Comment: "When $n=2$ all the values are $1$"?

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove that part.

Comment: When $n=2$, don't we have $a_2(0,0)=p^2,\ a_2(0,1)=p(1-p),$ etc?

Comment: Yes, thank you.